# Django REST API configurations receiving image from android

Tags: android, json, django

Hi I am new to Django and I am currently using it to create a web service. I am connecting android to django and would like to upload and image from android to django imagefield. I am using serializer to save the data in json. this code works on normal web, however, I am not sure what image file format to send over to the server and how to configure the server's file handling

This is what my `views.py` looks like :

```
`def post(self, request):
serializer = PhotoSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
 serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`
```

Comment: Hi. I have already done the serializer class. Now im sending json with the image url from android, i was wondering how can i process it in the server

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should try to create a serializers class for save the image from that way:

```
class ModelNameSaveSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_field = serializers.ImageField()
    class Meta:
       model = ModelName
       fields = ('id'.. antoher_fields, 'image_field')
```

Comment: Hi. I have already done the serializer class. Now im sending json with the image url from android, i was wondering how can i process it in the server